# Remove subelement from a yaml array in bash/awk when there's no order?

Tags: awk

I'm trying to find a better way of removing values from a yaml, for example - this is my yaml example:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  mapRoles: |-
    - username: user1
      rolearn: arn
      groups:
        - grp
        - grp2
    - groups:
        - grp
      rolearn: arn
      username: user2
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"..."}
  uid: 93ad6dc1-2a1f-11ea-b5da-0ec0e91c7076
```

my input is list of user names, which i can test with regex **or**. as i cannot install any dependencies, i have to use a tool that is installed in any system - thats what i chose awk.

in each part, i have to check the username if it matches any list of values, then if it does - remove a specific group from the "groups:" list.

what i was thinking is to identify each start of a yaml key (that represents a user) - then, add everything to an array while checking if the username is exactly what we expect - if it does, print the array but without the relevant group, else - print the entire array.

i've started writing it and it seems complex - is there any better way?

--- examples ---

If i'm specifying "user1" and the "grp" as the params, yaml should look like:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  mapRoles: |-
    - username: user1
      rolearn: arn
      groups:
        - grp2
    - groups:
        - grp
      rolearn: arn
      username: user2
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"..."}
  uid: 93ad6dc1-2a1f-11ea-b5da-0ec0e91c7076
```

if i'm specifying user2 and the "grp", it should look like:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  mapRoles: |-
    - username: user1
      rolearn: arn
      groups:
        - grp
        - grp2
    - groups:
      rolearn: arn
      username: user2
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"..."}
  uid: 93ad6dc1-2a1f-11ea-b5da-0ec0e91c7076
```

That's my issue - basically the user2 is specified AFTER the groups section, which then i'm not sure about the correct way to remove it.

Comment: IMHO experts always advise to parse ymal files with a tool/language which understands better eg--> `yq`, by any chance you have this in your system? Or you could install it in your box? So that solutions could be given as per your answer.

Comment: sadly no, i require to use the most basic tools that are installed out of the box

Comment: Is what you posted REALLY what your yaml looks like, i.e. with both username and groups sometimes preceded by `-` and sometimes not? What if you remove the 1 group that's under `groups` or `- groups` - does the `groups` line remain or does it get removed when the final `grp` is removed? Please [edit] your question to show the expected output given your posted sample input plus what you've tried so far. See [ask].

Comment: updated my question, yes, basically i dont care if "-groups:" will stay, i just need to remove specific group for specific users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, by the note of Ed Morton, i've taken his script, but had to change the regex, as it didn't catch groups with colons in the name (such as - my:group)

```
BEGIN {
    inGroups = 0
    split(users,tmp)
    for (i in tmp) {
        tgtUsers[tmp[i]]
    }
    split(groups,tmp)
    for (i in tmp) {
        tgtGroups[tmp[i]]
    }
}
match($0,/^ +(-? (username|rolearn|userarn): [^ ]+|-? groups: *$)/) {
    sect = $0
    sub(/^[[:space:]]*(-[[:space:]]*)?/,"",sect)
    sub(/[[:space:]]*:.*/,"",sect)
    if ($1 == "-") {
      startIndexArr[NR]
      start_index = NR
    }
    inGroups = 0
}
sect == "username" {
    if ($NF in tgtUsers)
        relevantUsersIndexArr[start_index]
}
sect == "groups" {
    inGroups = 1
}
(inGroups == 1 && ($NF in tgtGroups)) {
    foundGroupsArr[NR]
}
{
    yamlArr[NR] = $0
}

END {
    row_num = 1
    for (i in yamlArr) {
        if (row_num in startIndexArr)
            start_entity_index = row_num

        print_row = 1
        if (row_num in foundGroupsArr && start_entity_index in relevantUsersIndexArr)
            print_row = 0

        if (print_row == 1)
            print yamlArr[row_num]
        row_num++
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This might be what you're trying to do but its not clear from your question:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    split(users,tmp)
    for (i in tmp) {
        tgtUsers[tmp[i]]
    }
    split(groups,tmp)
    for (i in tmp) {
        tgtGroups[tmp[i]]
    }
}
match($0,/^[[:space:]]*(-[[:space:]]*)?[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]*:/) {
    sect = $0
    sub(/^[[:space:]]*(-[[:space:]]*)?/,"",sect)
    sub(/[[:space:]]*:.*/,"",sect)
}
sect == "username" {
    inTgtUsers = ($NF in tgtUsers)
    inGroups = 0
}
sect == "groups" {
    inGroups = 1
}
!(inGroups && inTgtUsers && ($NF in tgtGroups))
```

```
$ awk -v users='user1' -v groups='grp' -f tst.awk file
apiVersion: v1
data:
  mapRoles: |-
    - username: user1
      rolearn: arn
      groups:
        - grp2
    - groups:
      rolearn: arn
      username: user2
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"..."}
  uid: 93ad6dc1-2a1f-11ea-b5da-0ec0e91c7076
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks but not exactly, if you pass only "user1" as parameter, the 2nd group should not be removed, if you specify "user2", then the grp1 of only that user should be removed.
that's where it got a bit complicated for me - as the "username: user2" is declared after the groups section, so how can i verify that this section contains the user i want?

Comment: OK, then you need to read each whole `- username:` and `- groups:` section into a buffer (array or string) and then analyze that for the username(s) and groups(s) you care about then modify and print the buffer. It's not hard to do, I personally just cant be bothered writing the code to do it, hopefully someone else will have the time to help you with that.